Bad memory address problem on qtspim (assembly code)
I keep getting a bad memory address error on this code please help. This code is supposed to reverse the string stored on STR_str.
       reverse_string:

       
    li            $t3, 0                    # set iterator to 0

    la            $a0, STR_str              # $a0 = addressof(STR_str[0])
    jal           string_length             # jumps to string length function
    
    addi          $t1, $v0, -1              # load offset for index of last element to t1   

    la            $t0, STR_str              # load address of string to t0

    loop_start:
    
    sll           $t4, $t3, 2               # t3 = t3*4 computes for offset
    add           $t4, $t4, $t0             # add offset to base address

    sll           $t5, $t1, 2               # t5 = t1*4 computes for offset
    add           $t5, $t5, $t0             # add offset to base address

    lw            $t7, 0($t4)               # load item to $t7
    sw            $t5, 0($t4)               # store t5 to t4
    sw            $t7, 0($t5)               # store t7 to t5

    addi          $t3, $t3, 1
    addi          $t1, $t1, -1

    bge           $t1, $t3, loop_end        # jump to end if index 1 and 2 overlap

    j             loop_start                #------^


    loop_end:

    jr            $ra


I think the problem is on register t4 as I see it on my qtspim
also here is string_length:
    string_length:

    #### Write your solution here ####
    add $v0, $zero, $zero       #Initialize counter to zero
    move $t0, $a0               #Move the address of the string
    
loop:
    lb $t1, ($t0)               #Load t0 into t1
    beq $t1, $zero, end_all     #Done if t1 == NULL
    addi $v0, $v0, 1            #Increment counter
    addi $t0, $t0, 1            #Move to next character
    j loop                      #next

end_all:

    jr  $ra                     #Return to caller


That code is working with words not bytes.  Strings are bytes, are you trying to reverse an array of words or string of bytes?
